# ArcGIS WAB Layerlist Popup Opacity

Tags: arcgis-web-appbuilder, widget

I'm having an issue with the Layer list popup menu in my WAB apps being slightly transparent, which can make the layer names harder to read.  I would like to set the background opacity to 100% so that the map cannot be seen behind it.

I'm creating the apps w/ WAB Dev Edition and using the foldable theme.  I can't seem to find the setting for the menu opacity anywhere - just transparency settings for the individual layers.

Where can I find and change this setting?  None of the other widgets I'm using seem to have this issue.

Comment: Can you provide a screen shot? I have a default install (nothing changed), with the foldable theme and the layer list and nothing is transparent. All parts of it are solid white.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue turned out to be that I had the layer lists grouped.  For anyone else who has this issue, here's the solution from Robert Scheitlin w/ Esri:

Insert the following code into the theme common file at themes\FoldableTheme\common.css:

.jimu-panel {
background-color: white;
}

Once I did that, it fixed the opacity issue.